# How do I determine target commit of a git fixup commit?

Tags: git

After creating fixup git commits, is there are way to show or cat-file or something the commit and figure out it's target commit?
Specifically I don't want to have to guess and check all the time with rebase -i to find out that my rebase target is sufficiently back far enough in history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you mean a commit generated with  `git commit --fixup`.

Git uses the first line of the fixup commit's commit message, which looks similar to this:

```
fixup! Remove some foos from bars
```

To find this commit, you can <strike>use the exact same method that Git itself will use: it searches</strike> let Git search back in the history until it finds a commit that begins with the text after the `fixup!` token. The magic command is:

```
git show 'HEAD^{/Remove some foos}'
```

This will search back beginning at `HEAD` and show the first commit matching the text in the braces (sans `/`, which is an instruction for *search the following text*).

---

EDIT: I was really confused when I tested stuff in Windows CMD (in particular, its treatment of `^`). As @torek points out in the comments, `^{/xyz}` syntax does a match of the given regular expression on the entire commit message. Therefore, it is necessary to anchor the regular expression at the beginning of the text. The correct command is:

```
git show 'HEAD^{/^Remove some foos}'
```

Comment: Note that the `rev^{text}` syntax searches the entire commit message of each commit, while the `--fixup` logic in `git rebase -i` searches only the subjects (`git log` with format `%s`) of the commits that appear in the list of commits the rebase will cherry-pick. But this is going to be the way to go in most cases—constructing a "proper" search is too hard in general.

Comment: This doesn't exactly work and in fact ends up showing the contents of the fixup commit, not the on that will be updated.
I created a contrived repo with an initial commit, then two commits with the same message and finally a fixup commit targeting the older of the two commits with the same message. Git does keep track of the target as it chose the correct one if during an interactive rebase.

Comment: @pksublime It worked for me, but it was on Windows, and `^` behaves a bit strange there. You can always skip one commit by using `HEAD^^{/...}`.

Comment: @j6t I'm on windows too, and in my contrived example repo i'm looking for the 3rd back. The rebase command actually finds the right message, so this isn't how the tool is determining the 'target' of the fixup commit. There must be some meta data stored in it somewhere.

Comment: @pksublime No, there is no metadata. `rebase` finds the commit purly based on the text that follows the `fixup!` token.

Comment: @j6t i have a repo proving otherwise

Comment: @pksublime Is the repo accessible somewhere?

Comment: @pksublime I guess you have just have been lucky. Do not use ambiguous commit subjects. `rebase` does not use the revision walker to look for a matching commit, but uses its own lookup hash table. I can't tell what it does with ambiguous commit subjects. Take-away message: make your commit subjects unique.

Comment: @j6t This is of course a contrived example, but it does prove that somewhere the single commit the fixup commit was created against is stored somewhere. Which leaves me still curious how rebase knows how to pick the correct commit.

Comment: @pksublime I explained it: it's a [plain textual search](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f1d4a28250629ae469fc5dd59ab843cb2fd68e12/sequencer.c#L5220). No magic involved. You have been lucky that it picked the commit of the two candidates that you expected.

Comment: @j6t I did another test, and the fixup was placed where you said it would be. I did a much longer set of bad commits and tried to fixup the first one. My apologies, I was confused about which commit the fixup was attached to in the rebase list (the one above it or the one below it). The further separation made it more obvious.